# Is there a way to update WP7 application without asking user to use Market?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm wondering if there is some legal way to update WP7 application without asking user to go Market and download new version?

What I want to achieve is to make an app and install it manualy on some devices (without using Market). Then the app should ask user to install update. As I installed it manualy on my device, I'm not able to use Market for updates, don't I?

The business use case is to preinstall (manualy) some dummy app on devices, and then prepare reall app. When reall app is finished I would like to inform users about that, and ask them to update.

I'm not a WP7 developer, but I need to know if there's some way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

No , there is no way to do that , may be in the future after lunching Windows phone 8 they add more features to the Marketplace

Answer (score 1):

[From what I understand](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2011/04/15/mango-adds-beta-and-private-marketplaces-to-windows-phone-7-and-neglects-enterprise/), whilst there is not yet (as of Mango) any way to update without using MarketPlace, you can publish the app as a private app (along with all the certification requirements) and only using that are given a deep link to the store can install it (and then get updates) - it is only privacy through obscurity, so be careful - it should not be used as an option for exposing corporate data without secondary authentication.

From a user experience perspective, and to assist in certification; It would be advisable to develop an app that is at least partially usuable even if it was an app (theoretic example time) for buying concert tickets, to only list upcoming concerts in the dummy version. At least then if people poked it, they may be inclined to come back later (rather than just uninstall it)